# is it possible to telnet and do conversation using expect via android app

Tags: android, expect

I want to know if the idea below can be implemented via android app .
My system creates a wifi network (say 'w') and when we connect our android phone to 'w' then our phone will get ip 192.168.1.x and gateway will be 192.168.1.1
Now we will open our android app and press 'run' button in it then it will do following things in background .

```
telnet 192.168.1.1
Login:root
Password:something
>ifconfig eth0 | grep HWaddr
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:04:95:99:8F:1A
>sh
BusyBox v1.17.2 (2021-05-31 16:16:26 IST) built-in shell (ash)<br>
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
#bs /b/e gpon | grep link_operational_state
      pon_link_state : {admin_state=active,sub_
 overhead_cfg->overhead_repetition 170
state=operational,link_operational_state=operational o5}
```

I have written an example above to show that i want to run such commands and extract relevant words from output like "00:04:95:99:8F:1A" and "o5" which i will show on GUI of android app.
I am able to simulate such conversation using spawn , expect script in linux .

Can you suggest if it is possible in android and can you point me to useful links for this purpose .

Thanks .

Comment: Have you installed Expect on the system?

Comment: in a linux desktop i found expect command inbuilt . i do not know if android has inbuilt support for expect or library is available which can be integrated into app .